# How do i access an element of an object that is inside an array and that array is inside an object

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, multidimensional-array, javascript-objects

I need a small Help in JS? i want to access mail_address of this nested object, how will I do it

```
const data = 
  { members: 
    [ { id           : '7d8c03e88a8386f6453340c1db56'
      , mail_address : 'trial.om'
      , uniqsl       : 'c6cce01'
  } ] }
```

Comment: `data.members[0].mail_address` should do... Did you try anything prior to ask?

Answer (score 2):

```js
const data = {
  members: [
   {
    id: '7d8c03e88a8386f6453340c1db56',
    mail_address: 'trial.om',
    uniqsl: 'c6cce01',
    }
   ]
}

console.log(data.members[0].mail_address) // Prints "trail.om"
```

`members` is a array of objects, but it has one single element. You access this element at the index 0.

Comment: i get an error saying saying "Cannot Read properties of undefined ( reading "0") ,,, I am using Mailchimp api

Comment: During my edits i renamed obj as data to follow the question example, but forgot to rename it in the console

Comment: yeah i used this   console.log(data.members[0].mail_address);

Comment: still getting an error!

Comment: The `data` as the variable name of the object comes from the edit of @MisterJojo. -- Shubam, check the name of the object.

Comment: @MisterJojo: that is a good example why **not** to add anything to questions. Be careful ;)

Comment: Wat! A random person can edit the asker question! Didn't know that

Comment: @EduPaz Not "random"... A user who has the privilege (2K rep points) - [ref](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges)

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette Shubham Vishwakarma  is a newbie here, I just tried to make his question more readable...

Comment: A random >=2k rep points user 

Comment: @EduPaz: It is useful most of the time. Did you notice MY edit to your answer? (lol)

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette fair enough